# Gravity Forms: Multi-Page Form Validation

Tags: validation, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a field 47 on Page 1 and a field 55 on Page 3 of a form. How do I create a gform_validation on Page 3 to prompt an error message when Field 47 < Field 55? The code below works for validation if both fields are on same page but it doesn't work for multi-page. Any idea plz?

Thanks!

```
// multi-page validation
add_filter( 'gform_validation', 'custom_validation' );
function custom_validation( $validation_result ) {
    $form = $validation_result['form'];

    // Financial Assets must be larger than Investment
    if ( rgpost( 'input_47' ) < rgpost( 'input_55' )  ) {

        // set the form validation to false
        $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

        //finding Field with ID of 1 and marking it as failed validation
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

            //NOTE: replace 1 with the field you would like to validate
            if ( $field->id == '34' ) {
                $field->failed_validation = true;
                $field->validation_message = 'Your Financial Assets (A) cannot be lower than your investment with us. Please fix the discrepancy.';
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    //Assign modified $form object back to the validation result
    $validation_result['form'] = $form;
    return $validation_result;

}
```

I found the following information on their documentation however I'm not sure how to implement it inside the code above. Any clue? Thanks alot!

```
// 3 - Get the current page being validated
$current_page = rgpost( 'gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id'] ) ? rgpost( 'gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id'] ) : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the submitted page via the `GFFormDisplay::get_source_page( $form_id )` method.

There are a few different ways this could be done. For simplicity, I would just bypass validation until your desired page is submitted. To do that, just add something like this:

```
if( GFFormDisplay::get_source_page( $form_id ) >= 3 ) {
    return $validation_result;
}
```

...after this line:

```
 $form = $validation_result['form'];
```

This would only run this validation on pages greater than page 3.